# Integrating a discontinuous function

Tags: differential-equations

```
p = -1; q = 2;
f'[x_] = Piecewise[{{3 x, x <= 1/3}, {-3 x + 2 + p, 
    1/3 < x <= 2/3}, {3 x - 1 + q, 2/3 < x}}]
Plot[f'[x], {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]
NDSolve[{f'[x] == Cos[x], f[0] == .5}, f, {x, 0, 1}];
h[u_] = f[u] /. First[%];
Plot[h[u], {u, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

How to change the discontinuous integrand so as to make it recognizable as  a regular differential  equation?

Comment: It looks like you are integrating f', which has no dependence on the p and q values (they only enter g').

Comment: Thanks, mistake corrected. Should the integrand be a single smooth function?